# Maximum response size in Apache reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I am using elasticsearch behind my Apache reverse proxy. I have 600 GB of data in elasticsearch and each time a user tries to search a file, the request will pass through my reverse proxy. So what is the maximum response size that the reverse proxy can handle?